# Why ImageMagick command convert recognize only 'Courier' as font?

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to create an image-text file with the follow ImageMagick command:

```
convert -background black -fill red -font Courier -pointsize 72 label:MyText test.jpg
```

With the above command it's all ok while if instead of 'Courier' I set another one of the many fonts that looks like to be installed on my system (Mint-17.3) it returns only error messages.

Comment: "Courier" is not necessarily installed, & it wouldn't surprise me if ImageMagick does no guessing at all for a close match.

Comment: You have look at the [available fonts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392858/with-imagemagick-how-can-you-see-all-available-fonts) from ImageMagick's perspective? These don't necessarily match all installed fonts.